# What is causing my AssertionError when trying to implement Allauth with Django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to implement Allauth to work in conjuction with my custom user model in Django. When I try to run the server I receive the following readout in the console:

```
File "X:\Aidan Comer\Documents\Portfolio_Projects\game_ecommerce_site\venv\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\app_settings.py", line 373, in <module>
    app_settings = AppSettings("ACCOUNT_")
  File "X:\Aidan Comer\Documents\Portfolio_Projects\game_ecommerce_site\venv\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\app_settings.py", line 20, in __init__
    assert (
AssertionError
```

My custom user model is:

```
class UserBase(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    country = CountryField()
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(max_length=8)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    town_city = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars', default='default-user-avatar.png')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    objects = CustomAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name',
                        'last_name', 'country', 'phone_number', 
                        'date_of_birth', 'town_city',]
```

Here are my settings concerning Allauth and google Oauth implementation:

```
# Allauth and Oauth login settings
SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET=True

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
    ]

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "email"

ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = False

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile',
            'email',
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'access_type': 'online',
        }
    }
}
```

Why am I receiving this AssertionError?

Comment: it seems that the error is caused by a missing `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED` setting. This setting specifies whether a user's email address is required for account registration. By default, `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED` is set to `True`, but since you're using a custom user model that already includes an email field, you can set `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED` to `False`. Make sure to add this setting to your Django settings file and try running the server again.

Comment: This did not get the server running. However, by adding: ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True, it ran successfully

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Sorry, accidentally posted before finishing comment.